# Swipe navigation not working

Tags: javascript, html, ios, jquery-mobile

Not sure if its the way that I am writing it, but when I try to utilize jquery mobiles change page function on swipe, it wont allow me to swipe to a specific page. I want the user to be able to swipe and get to a home page no matter where they are. Heres what I have.

```
<script>
 $( document ).bind( "swiperight", page, function() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "#home", { 
    transition: "slide", 
    reverse: true } );
    });

</script>
```

Javascript isnt my strongest language but I know enough that this should work. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens when you try to swipe? Does your page just scroll and then bounce back?

Comment: it just doesn't do anything. It looks like its not recognizing the swipe at all

Comment: Does you home page has `id="home"`?

Comment: yeah, everything is correct as far as id's and such

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to do

```
$(document).swiperight(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#home", { 
        transition: "slide", 
        reverse: true
    });
});
```

or

```
$('body').swiperight(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#home", { 
        transition: "slide", 
        reverse: true
    });
});
```

[Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxzZf/4/) (not by me) that you could refer to.

Comment: Yeah still not working, not sure whats going on with it. I had it set up before where on swipe, it would just go back to the pervious page in the history but it was becoming problematic as the project grew.